# Building a Lambda Expression with Where Clause on multiple joined tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have to add a `.Where()` clause on the `db1` table in my LINQ query that looks something like this:

```
var query = from db1 in db.db1
                              join db2 in db.database2 on db1.atr1 equals db2.atr1
                              join db3 in db.database3 on db1.atr1 equals db3.atr1
                              select new { db1, db2, db3};
```

I have added a Lambda expression to a query where there is not the join clause, but can't figure out when you have these "nested" tables. Instead of:

`query = query.Where(t => t.attr5.Contains("String"));`

It would have to be:

`query = query.Where(t => t.db1.attr5.Contains("String"));`

My code to build the lambda for the `Where()` looks like this:

```
ParameterExpression eParam = Expression.Parameter(tableType, "innerTable");
MethodInfo method = filterValue.GetType().GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) }); // filterValue is just a string
MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(Expression.Property(eParam, filterField), method, Expression.Constant(filterValue));
Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, eParam);
currentQuery = currentQuery.Where(lambda);
```

`tableType` is a variable where I get the `PropertyType` for a table with the select new statement, but it will throw and error since it doesn't match the object `select new { db1, db2, db3 }`.

I am assuming I need to make another:

`ParameterExpression eParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");`? and somehow `.` that before the `MethodCallExpression`, not sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I had to take from this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18896870/6368685

But I am not using:

```
var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(expression, parameter);
return lambdaExpression;
```

Instead, I take the `expression` variable and pass it into the MethodCallExpression I need to build before building the lambda:

```
MethodInfo method = filterValue.GetType().GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(expression, method, Expression.Constant(filterValue));
Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, argLambda);
currentQuery = currentQuery.Where(lambda);
```